# What is the covalent radius of different molecules of different atoms?

Tags: elements

I mean the covalent radius of different molecules of same atoms  is one half of the distance between the nuclei. Then what is the covalent radius of molecules of different atoms.

Answer (score 2):

Molecules don't have a covalent radius, only atoms that make up molecules through covalent bonds have a covalent radius. Even then it's a slightly tortured concept, in my view.

Atoms however do not possess a *single* covalent radius. The bond length (inter-nuclear distances of bonded atoms) varies considerably from one bond type to the next.

In particular triple bonds ($\sigma$ + 2 $\pi$) are shorter than double bonds ($\sigma$ + 1 $\pi$), which in turn are shorter than single bonds ($\sigma$ only). This is due to increased inter-nuclear electron shielding for triple and double bonds. The higher the shielding, the closer the nuclei can be, because their electrostatic repulsion is reduced.

In addition, in single bonds, the participating Atomic Orbitals also matter: $\sigma_{ss}$ are not exactly the same as $\sigma_{sp}$ or $\sigma_{pp}$ bonds.

Difference in Pauling electronegativity also influences bond length somewhat.

Despite that, [average covalent radii for different atoms have been computed, see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_radius).